# How to delete from table using JOIN statement?

Tags: mysql

None of the examples that I found work in my case. I have 2 tables:

`items` with `cat_id`; and
`catalog` with `id`

I would like to delete all records from `items` that are not in `catalog`.

Thanks.

Comment: What examples? The ones in the official manual for example usually work like a charm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
delete i
from items i
left join catalog c on c.id = i.cat_id
where c.id is null
```

Answer (score 2):

You can delete using left join as demonstrated in some other answers, but this one works just as well and is more portable to other databases that don't always support the left join construct in delete statements.

```
delete from items
where cat_id not in (select id from catalog)
```

By the way, if you have proper foreign key constraints, it shouldn't be possible that items exist that refer to a non-existent category. I think you should consider putting those constraints in place.

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM items i
LEFT JOIN catalog c ON i.cat_id = c.id 
WHERE c.id IS NULL;
```